# css for mozila and css for chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, mozilla

I would like to ask about a centering problem i have with a `<p>` on mozilla and firefox. You know, it looks nice on chrome but not on mozilla.

Here the css I'm trying to tweak:

```
.center-bottom, -moz-div.center-bottom  {
  align-content: center;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 23%;
  margin-top: -6px;
}
```

Here it is on chrome:
http://imagizer.imageshack.us/v2/1024x768q90/546/725z.jpg

On firefox:
http://imageshack.com/a/img855/5242/ya5y.jpg

The first line inside the stroked line is a javascript printing the line. And I want to center that together with the second line on both mozilla and chrome and IE.

From my research I saw about -moz-,-webkit-, and top,left etc (the old margins) but I can't seem to make them work!

Comment: `-moz-div` is an invalid class, I believe. Also `align-content` only works with flexbox AFAIK https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/align-content

Comment: Also. I think a `div` in a `p` is invalid HTML

Comment: instead off image provide the respective CSS(i.e. CSS of footer class)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should try to make it work with standard css at first rather than applying browser specific styles. For me it looks like using simple `text-align: center` should do the work. But its impossible to tell you exactly since you do not provide real code.

```
.center-bottom {
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto;
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LMxXa/2/)

Comment: As I said, if you don't provide a real example it's difficult to say which styles/elements are causing problems. I created a fiddle example to show that you don't need to do something fancy to center text in the footer.

Comment: @user3246028 If you have found the problem, then you could update your question with the problematic code snippet (a short one) and add some short explanation (a comment or an answer would be OK). That way you would *help other* persons who might also have similar problem.